# Reconstructing a string manipulated with bitwise operations

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, inverse, bitwise-and

Suppose I have a Java string of length 32, e.g.

```
String s = "Y7yEdfjQ2qmpGZbPYswKIdxYVo6KnR9M";
```

I'm looking for the string t with the following property: *If the following loop is performed on t, the resulting string is s*:

```
char[] tArr = t.toCharArray();
for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    tArr[i] = (char) (tArr[i] ^ tArr[i * 123456 % 31] & 31);
}
```

Note that in Java the array operator [] has highest precedence and bitwise AND is evaluated before bitwise XOR.

In order to obtain t the reverse operation must be applied to s. The inverse operation of XOR is XOR, however the logical AND obviously has no inverse operation.

Can the string t be recovered short of bruteforcing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop takes in each iteration two chars, and xors the first char with the lowest 5 bits of the other char. That means that the top 3 bits remain unchanged. They don't get lost. In fact the top 3 bits of `t[i]` are equal to the top 3 bits of `s[i]`, and we only have to find the lowest 5 bits of the characters in the original string `t`.

Now, lets calculate `i * 123456 % 31`, and see what the loop actually does in each iteration :

```
t[1] = t[1] ^ (t[14]&31)
t[2] = t[2] ^ (t[28]&31)
t[3] = t[3] ^ (t[11]&31)
t[4] = t[4] ^ (t[25]&31)
t[5] = t[5] ^ (t[8]&31)
t[6] = t[6] ^ (t[22]&31)
t[7] = t[7] ^ (t[5]&31)
t[8] = t[8] ^ (t[19]&31)
t[9] = t[9] ^ (t[2]&31)
t[10] = t[10] ^ (t[16]&31)
t[11] = t[11] ^ (t[30]&31)
t[12] = t[12] ^ (t[13]&31)
t[13] = t[13] ^ (t[27]&31)
t[14] = t[14] ^ (t[10]&31)
t[15] = t[15] ^ (t[24]&31)
t[16] = t[16] ^ (t[7]&31)
t[17] = t[17] ^ (t[21]&31)
t[18] = t[18] ^ (t[4]&31)
t[19] = t[19] ^ (t[18]&31)
t[20] = t[20] ^ (t[1]&31)
t[21] = t[21] ^ (t[15]&31)
t[22] = t[22] ^ (t[29]&31)
t[23] = t[23] ^ (t[12]&31)
t[24] = t[24] ^ (t[26]&31)
t[25] = t[25] ^ (t[9]&31)
t[26] = t[26] ^ (t[23]&31)
t[27] = t[27] ^ (t[6]&31)
t[28] = t[28] ^ (t[20]&31)
t[29] = t[29] ^ (t[3]&31)
t[30] = t[30] ^ (t[17]&31)
t[31] = t[31] ^ (t[0]&31)
```

We know that after the final iteration, the array has been transformed from `t` (which we don't know) to `s` (which we know - "Y7yEdfjQ2qmpGZbPYswKIdxYVo6KnR9M").

Now, since `t[0]` is never modified, we know that `s[0]=t[0]='Y'` (or 01011001 in binary).

This gives us `t[31]` easily :

```
t[0]&31 = 00011001
s[31] = 'M' = 01001101 = t[31] ^ 00011001
```

xor both sides, and get :

```
t[31] = 01001101 ^ 00011001 = 01010100
```

The other characters are less easy.

The iterations of the loop form two cycles :

```
1->14->10->16->7->5->8->19->18->4->25->9->2->28->20->1

3->11->30->17->21->15->24->26->23->12->13->27->6->22->29->3
```

Now, lets try finding other characters of `t` :

`t[30] = t[30] ^ (t[17]&31)`

after this assignment, `t[30]` becomes `s[30]`, i.e. '9' or 00111001.

We know that `001 11001 = 001 ????? ^ 000 xxxxx`

Where ????? are the lowest 5 bits of `t[30]` and xxxxx are the lowest 5 bits of `t[17]`. But actually, it's not the original `t[17]`. By the time we assign `t[30]`, `t[17]` has already been updated to its final value, which we know (it's `s[17]` - 's' or `01110011`).

Therefore `001 11001 = 001 ????? ^ 000 10011`.

And if we xor both sides, `001 11001 ^ 000 10011 = 001 01010`

so the original `t[30]` is 00101010.

So far I found `t[0]`,`t[30]` and `t[31]`.
I believe (though I haven't actually checked), that I can go on and find all the other characters of `t` this way.

The important thing to pay attention to when we calculate `t[i]` is that if `t[i]` depends on `t[j]` such that `i<j`, it depends on the original value of `t[j]` (the unknown), while if `i>j`, it depends on the final value of `t[j]` (which is `s[j]` - which we know).

Comment: That's really nice explanation, but since it really cuts things down to 5 bits allowed - then it's not possible to decrypt it in real life. However for some edicational purpose, considering letters to be encoded from 1 to 26 - that *might* be possible to resolve it back. Thanks!

Comment: @jdevelop But as I explained, it doesn't cut things to 5 bits. you have `tArr[i] = (char) (tArr[i] ^ tArr[i * 123456 % 31] & 31)`, which to simplify we can write as `t[i]=t[i]^t[j]&31`. Since the AND is evaluated before the XOR, you are XORing t[i] with the low 5 bits of t[j]. That means that the top 3 bits of t[i] remain unchanged, and therefore they are not lost, and you only have to find the 5 lowest bits, and I showed how to do that.

Comment: I missed the point of priority of logical operators, true. I believe that in this case the reversing is quite possible, because, let's see for the "terminal" case (last symbol):

- a[i] = 238
- a[j] = 11

so applying the same function

229 ^ 11 & 31

it will give us 238.

Applying it back:

238 ^ 11 & 31

And that's it

Comment: I had followed the same line of thought but discarded it because of a mistake in my calculation. I wish I could upvote you twice, Eran!

Comment: @lpradel Glad I could help! It was an interesting question

Answer (score 3):

31 is 11111b

so the algorithm takes lowest 5 bits of any char, which gives you no option to recover the initial string - you may find out some string which leads to the same hash

and the brute-force is the only option here

Comment: I believe you mean 31 is 0b11111 (and 0x1F)?

Comment: yeah, really, I probably thought about something else.